# Some good reading on polygon algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, cg.comp-geom

What are some good resources (books, articles, sites) about polygon intersection and union algorithms?

Comment: It depends what you want to do - there are different communities working on this issues from graphics, computational geometry to CAD...

Answer (score 2):

I found this book to cover the topics well

Computational Geometry in C
by Joseph O'Rourke

Answer (score 0):

[The monograph by Preparata and Shamos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540961313) is worth looking at. Despite the name it's quite deep.

Comment: ...and it is also completely outdated.